# Parsing element using jsoup in Java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am using jsoup in my java app to parse html code but now I need parse table data and I want to get the first  value of the first `<td>` element under `<tr>` and after that if the first data contains the word "Outdated" it will skip and if there is no outdated it will parse to the 3rd table and get the value with ".rpm" word and can not get it to work. I try many ways but not successful so I want try luck here if anyone have experience.

```
public class rpms {

    public static void getTdSibling(String sourceTd) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String fragment = sourceTd;
        Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(fragment);
        Elements myElements = doc.getElementsByClass("confluenceTable tablesorter").first().getElementsByTag("tr");
        for (Element element : myElements) {
            if (element.select("td").contains("Outdated")) {
                String rpms = element.ownText();
                System.out.println(rpms);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URLget rpms = new URLget();
        try {
            getTdSibling(sendGetRequest(URL).toString());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And please see the HTML code under table where the parsing of element happens below :

```html
<table class="confluenceTable tablesorter">
    <tbody class="">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">RHSA-2014:1172</td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
                <p>The procmail program is used for local mail delivery. In addition to just
                    <br>delivering mail, procmail can be used for automatic filtering, presorting,
                    <br>and other mail handling jobs.</p>
                <p>A heap-based buffer overflow flaw was found in procmail's formail utility.
                    <br>A remote attacker could send an email with specially crafted headers that,
                    <br>when processed by formail, could cause procmail to crash or, possibly,
                    <br>execute arbitrary code as the user running formail. (CVE-2014-3618)
                </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">procmail-3.22-17.1.2.x86_64.rpm</td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
                <img class="emoticon emoticon-tick" src="/s/en_GB-1988229788/4733/f235dd088df5682b0560ab6fc66ed22c9124c0be.57/_/images/icons/emoticons/check.png" data-emoticon-name="tick" alt="(tick)">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">Outdated RHSA-2014:1166</td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
                <p>Jakarta Commons HTTPClient implements the client side of HTTP standards.</p>
                <p>It was discovered that the HTTPClient incorrectly extracted host name from
                    <br>an X.509 certificate subject's Common Name (CN) field. A man-in-the-middle
                    <br>attacker could use this flaw to spoof an SSL server using a specially
                    <br>crafted X.509 certificate. (CVE-2014-3577)</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
                <p>jakarta-commons-httpclient-3.0-7jpp.4.el5_10.x86_64.rpm</p>
                <p>jakarta-commons-httpclient-demo-3.0-7jpp.4.el5_10.x86_64.rpm</p>
                <p>jakarta-commons-httpclient-javadoc-3.0-7jpp.4.el5_10.x86_64.rpm</p>
                <p>jakarta-commons-httpclient-manual-3.0-7jpp.4.el5_10.x86_64.rpm</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">RHSA-2014:1148-1</td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
                <p>A flaw was found in the way Squid handled malformed HTTP Range headers.
                    <br>A remote attacker able to send HTTP requests to the Squid proxy could use
                    <br>this flaw to crash Squid. (CVE-2014-3609)
                </p>
                <p>A buffer overflow flaw was found in Squid's DNS lookup module. A remote
                    <br>attacker able to send HTTP requests to the Squid proxy could use this flaw
                    <br>to crash Squid. (CVE-2013-4115)</p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"><span>squid-2.6.STABLE21-7.el5_10.x86_64.rpm</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Need your help. I have tried many times and read articles from here but it can't. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with your element's accessors (see documentation [here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html)):

You can only give one class to `getElementsByClass`

```
public static void getTdSibling(String sourceTd) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String fragment = sourceTd;
    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(fragment);
    Elements myElements = doc.getElementsByClass("confluenceTable").first().getElementsByTag("tr");
    for (Element element : myElements) {
        // select the TDs
        Elements tds = element.getElementsByTag("td");
        // do you condition here
        if (tds.first().text().contains("Outdated")) {
            // access the <p> children of the 3rd td
            Elements rpms = tds.get(2).children();
            for (Element rpm : rpms) {
                if (rpm.text().contains(".rpm")) {
                    System.out.println(rpm.text());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edited, now access the 3rd td in a row.

Comment: Can you please modify this Elements `tds : element.getElementsByTag("td");` it is error.

Comment: Typo of mine, sorry. And a missing `;`